# Creating new File() or new Blob() crashes VSCode Extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, save-as

I am currently trying to save  a file with a "save as..." popup window in a vs code webview extension.

Things that i've already tried: using htmls "download" attribute in the webview, but the links just do nothing when clicking on them.

So i tried downloading a filesaver extension for nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2
the problem is, when i try to run this code in my vsCode extension:

```
var file = new File(["Hello, world!"], "hello world.txt", {type:
"text/plain;charset=utf-8"}); saveAs(file);
```

the creation of a new file causes my vscode extension to crash:

```
/C:/Users/hansel/…esktop.main.js:2786 Error: Running the contributed command: 'extension.helloWorld' failed. at _executeContributedCommand (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:549:316) at _.$executeContributedCommand (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:549:595) at p._doInvokeHandler (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:688:464) at p._invokeHandler (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:688:156) at p._receiveRequest (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:686:817) at p._receiveOneMessage (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:685:623) at c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:683:791 at l.fire (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:48:845) at v.fire (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:191:325) at c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:851:104 at l.fire (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:48:845) at v.fire (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:191:325) at Object._receiveMessage (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:195:717) at c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:192:897 at l.fire (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:48:845) at p.acceptChunk (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:188:897) at c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:188:249 at Socket.t (c:\Users\hansel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:197:232) at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13) at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12) at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11) at Socket.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10) at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
```

attempting to save a blob with msSaveOrOpenBlob

```
var blob = new Blob(["1","1"]);
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.docx');
```

results in the same error message when i try to create a blob

any way to get rid of theses errors and have a "save as..." function in a vs code extension?

Comment: Have you tried using VS Code's [FS api](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_vscodeworkspacefs) instead? It is the recommended approach for working with files as an extension. You'll need to use this from the main extension thread, not the webview

Comment: i dont really see the advantage here compared to fs: i want an OS level "save as..." dialog, which i can not get to work with either of these.

Comment: You should try it. The VS code fs api correctly handles many edge cases, such as working with a remote file system

Comment: i would be happy with having a save as dialog :c

Comment: Did you try `showSaveDialog` in the VS Code api?

Comment: i did not till now but it works perfectly, thanks!